# What exception is used to bring in public school records using CA evidence rules?

Tags: california, evidence

Is a record kept in the course of “business” at a public school admitted into evidence as a business record, public record or official government record under CA Evidence rules?

Answer (score 2):

One of the main reasons to exclude documentary evidence is that those documents are hearsay. But regularly kept records are an exception to the rule that hearsay is not admissible evidence.

This is set forth in [Article 7 of the California Evidence Code](https://law.justia.com/codes/california/2010/evid/1270-1272.html).